# HTTPS log-in to HTTP site

Tags: php, html, security

Just wondering is there a security advantage to creating a HTTPS log-in enviroment for a HTTP site ?

For various reasons making the entire site HTTP isn't really an option I was just wondering is it worth taking the effort to provide a HTTPS log-in even though users will be operating the rest of their logged in time within a non HTTPS enviroment ?

I did some googling and found that logging http into https isn't very secure but haven't been able to find a solid answer for the reverse scenario.

Would this sort of setup require two types of session data  a secure data that contains more private information and a more basic session that contained simply who the user is and that they are logged in, or could this be done safely with just the one piece of session data ?

Comment: Any site with any sort of login (privileges to post, modify, etc) you should use HTTPS on every page a logged-in user accesses, including the login page

Comment: I totally agree with you but that's just not an option with this case. The best case scenario is as I've mentioned sadly, I already had to fight to move away from mda5 hashing of passwords and not performance reasons or anything sensible just really silly obsessions of the site owner.

Basically I know what I'm suggesting isn't ideal, it's just the best thing I could come up with that can actually happen.

Comment: At the very least it will improve security somewhat, but not by much, your site will still be pretty vulnerable to attacks

Comment: I did assume it'd have to be better than nothing, I guess every little bit helps right ?

At the very least ill be able to keep passwords mostly secure.

Comment: I'm gonna add an answer, hold on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to explain the reason why HTTPS on the entire site would be best below:

Let's say you set up two pages on your site to be available through HTTPS:

```
/login.php
/loginhandler.php
```

`login.php` contains the login form, where the user inputs their username / password, and this form will submit to `loginhandler.php`.

This way, no one on your clients' network can modify this form when the user requests `login.php`, as it is served through HTTPS.

Your `loginhandler.php` is also served through HTTPS, so no one on any clients' network will be able to see the username / password they sent to the server when logging in.

*HOWEVER:*

If the rest of the "logged-in" content of the site is not in HTTPS, an attacker will be able to inject anything he wants (and see all the content the logged-in user requests).

For instance, he may inject a "You have been logged out, please provide your login details: (form)" message onto any page, where the form would submit to his own server instead of yours. Then the users' password will be compromised.

An attacker will also be able to inject malicious to the index of the site before the user has even gotten to `/login.php`, redirecting them to different sites, or even changing the address of the login button on your site.

Edit / A note om [MitM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack):

Man-in-the-middle attacks only work if the attacker has control of the network.
This can include (but is not limited to): your ISP, your employer at work, your neighbor if you connect to his network, etc.

Lastly, if an attacker wants to INJECT (change) content on a website, he will need to be targeting a specific website (this can of course be automated, usually for bigger volume sites). Listening for data is much easier than modifying it.

Comment: That gave me pretty much everything I wanted to know for each question I had and very concisely. Thanks a bunch for taking the time to write that out !

Answer (score 1):

A site's login page is definitely one of the most important pages to send over https as it will help prevent the user's password being intercepted when submitted via the login form.

Comment: So it's worth doing just for the log-in portal then ?

Do you have any thoughts on how session data should be handled ?